# How to parse sub path of an XML file using XML2 package

Tags: r, xml, tidyverse

I have the following [xml page](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P09429.xml) that looks like this which I need to parse using [xml2](https://github.com/r-lib/xml2)

[image]

However, with this code, I cannot get the list under the `subcellularLocation` xpath :

```
library(xml2)
xmlfile <- "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P09429.xml"

doc <- xmlfile %>%
  xml2::read_xml()

xml_name(doc)
xml_children(doc)
x <- xml_find_all(doc, "//subcellularLocation")
xml_path(x)
# character(0)
```

What is the right way to do it?

---

**Update**

```
The desired output is a vector:

[1] "Nucleus"                                                   
[2] "Chromosome"                                                
[3] "Cytoplasm"                                                 
[4] "Secreted"                                                  
[5] "Cell membrane"
[6] "Peripheral membrane protein" 
[7] "Extracellular side"
[8] "Endosome"                                                  
[9] "Endoplasmic reticulum-Golgi intermediate compartment"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `x <- xml_find_all(doc, "//d1:subcellularLocation")`

Whenever you meet a troublesome problem, check the document is the first thing to do, use `?xml_find_all` and you will see this (at the end of the page)

```
# Namespaces ---------------------------------------------------------------
# If the document uses namespaces, you'll need use xml_ns to form
# a unique mapping between full namespace url and a short prefix
x <- read_xml('
 <root xmlns:f = "http://foo.com" xmlns:g = "http://bar.com">
   <f:doc><g:baz /></f:doc>
   <f:doc><g:baz /></f:doc>
 </root>
')
xml_find_all(x, ".//f:doc")
xml_find_all(x, ".//f:doc", xml_ns(x))
```

So you then go to check `xml_ns(doc)` and find

```
d1  <-> http://uniprot.org/uniprot
xsi <-> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
```

**Update**

```
xml_find_all(doc, "//d1:subcellularLocation")
   %>% xml_children()
   %>% xml_text()

## [1] "Nucleus"                                             
## [2] "Chromosome"                                          
## [3] "Cytoplasm"                                           
## [4] "Secreted"                                            
## [5] "Cell membrane"                                       
## [6] "Peripheral membrane protein"                         
## [7] "Extracellular side"                                  
## [8] "Endosome"                                            
## [9] "Endoplasmic reticulum-Golgi intermediate compartment"ent"
```

Comment: If the answer solves your question, please click "accept" to mark it so others know that this problem has been solved

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind, you can use the `rvest` package:

```
library(rvest)
a=read_html(xmlfile)%>%
   html_nodes("subcellularlocation")

a%>%html_children()%>%html_text()

[1] "Nucleus"                                              "Chromosome"                                          
[3] "Cytoplasm"                                            "Secreted"                                            
[5] "Cell membrane"                                        "Peripheral membrane protein"                         
[7] "Extracellular side"                                   "Endosome"                                            
[9] "Endoplasmic reticulum-Golgi intermediate compartment"
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How can I get the content of sub-node (i.e. location)  under `subcellularlocation` node? (e.g. Nucleus, Chromosome, cytoplasm, etc)

Comment: @scamander What is your desired output? can you update your question with the desired output? jut a small example, should give one an idea of what you expect

Comment: @Scamander, does this solution not answer your question still?

Comment: but not quite there (e.g. Cell membrane etc, should be splitted)

Comment: See my answer (only use xml2)